# python matching on structures

Tags: python, data-structures, matching

I have two related questions.

First, i have a some information such as:

```
(732, 2378) (233, 52172) 23 ['Mona'] 7
```

There are two tuples, two integers and one list. Let us index the five items as x[0] : x[4]

My first question is what kind of data structure can I use to store these different items (sorry, I'm new to python).

The second is question is based on the first. Suppose I have such a structure (let's call it a list for now), my main objective then is to do the following:

Say in the first and second 'list' respective, I have:

```
 x[0][1]        x[1][1]    x[3]
   V               V        V
(732, 2378) (233, 23) 23 ['jamie'] 7 
(732, 2378) (233, 43) 24 ['jamie'] 3
(732, 2378) (233, 56) 23 ['jamie'] 2

(3434, 2378) (45, 23) 23 ['hello'] 1 
(3445, 2378) (76, 43) 23 ['hello'] 2
(7834, 2378) (90, 56) 24 ['hello'] 5
```

My objective is to traverse these two structures and match first on x[1][1] and x[2], then, for each matching record, find the corresponding x[4] that minimizes the sum of the values in all the matched items from both lists. Return the matched items from both structures.

In this case, it should return:
    (3445, 2378) (76, 43) 23 ['hello'] 2 
    AND (732, 2378) (233, 43) 24 ['jamie'] 3
Since the sum for this match, 5, is the minimum.

I know it's a bit involved but I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: You seem to have answered the first question yourself.  But what's the second question?

Comment: yes, i just figured i could use a dict for this with keys as the various x[i's] i want to store. the second question is described above.

primarily, say i've chosen to use a dict such that

dict = {'x0': '(23,23)', 'x1': '(2323, 34)', 'x2': '23', 'x3': '[the brave]', 'x4': 5'}

find an efficient way to search for the minimizing match as described above

Comment: ok, but what have you tried?  Do you have a search implementation that's not efficient?  If so, why do you think it's not efficient?

Comment: no, not yet. what i've come up with for storing the items is a list of tuples where each tuple contains x[1]:x[4]. is this a good implementation? if so, the problem is now the search. i can do a sort on x[4] and pick the first matches from both lists but this is not guaranteed to be min. so that's my search issue > i don't want to do n-squared comparisons. i'm hoping sorting on x[4] O(n lg n) should help reduce the running time for each of the million matches i have to make.

Comment: I would recommend getting your search ideas written down in code, then posting that code here and asking more concrete questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the data structures in your question are already reasonable -- just put them in list form.  If you use [named tuples](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), the search code will tend to be more readable than otherwise.  For the search/match code look at *[operator.attrgetter](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter)* and *[operator.itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)*.

For example, here is a convenient form to arrange the data (and depending on what the data actually represents, you can choose better names):

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Row = namedtuple('Row', ['Pair0', 'Pair1', 'Scalar0', 'Names', 'Scalar1'])
>>> d = [
         Row((732, 2378), (233, 23), 23, ['jamie'], 7),
         Row((732, 2378), (233, 43), 24, ['jamie'], 3),
         Row((732, 2378), (233, 56), 23, ['jamie'], 2),
         Row((3434, 2378), (45, 23), 23, ['hello'], 1),
         Row((3445, 2378), (76, 43), 23, ['hello'], 2),
         Row((7834, 2378), (90, 56), 24, ['hello'], 5),
]
```

[List comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) can be useful for the matching/filtering step:

```
>>> # filter on x[1][5] and x[2]
>>> e = [r for r in d if r.Pair1[1]==x and r.Scalar0==23]
>>> e
[Row(Pair0=(732, 2378), Pair1=(233, 23), Scalar0=23, Names=['jamie'], Scalar1=7),
 Row(Pair0=(3434, 2378), Pair1=(45, 23), Scalar0=23, Names=['hello'], Scalar1=1)
]
```

It isn't clear to me what you want to do for the step to minimize the sums, but hopefully there is enough in this answer to get you closer to the desired result :-)

Comment: thanks for the clear response. i have a data structure in place. to minimize the sums, the idea is i have d (as you have above) and also have, say f. d and f have several 'Rows' in them. of all these rows in both d and f, I only want one from each.

the task is to find that one from each that matches on pair[2] and scalar0, AND has the least value of d.scalar1 + f.scalar1

Comment: If I understand your next step correctly, then filter matches as shown above, group matches using *sorted* and *itertools.groupby*, for each group, and select the least value of d.scalar1+f.scalar1 using *min* with a *key* argument.

Comment: thanks for the pointers. i'll try things out and see what works.